# Flutter - Firebase Realtime Database only writes at second attempt

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I created a new Firebase project for some tests.
Somehow now it seems like the first writing attempt to the Firebase Realtime Database "databaseReference.child(A).set" doesn't write anything. At least I don't see it in the Database (Database is empty).

The second writing attempt "databaseReference.child(B).set" writes it fine and it shows up.

I only have this one  writing part in the code, so there is no change there is some kind of wrong directing.

But now it becomes strange:

When I read the data from child "A" I receive the information. So the data must be stored somewhere.
I am using the Firebase free plan, so I can only use one database, as far a I know.
I also checked my other Firebase projects.

Any idea what could be the cause or how I can check if the data is written correctly?

EDIT:

here is my code:

```
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    UserCredential userCredential =
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();


    final key = cryptokey.Key.fromLength(32);
    final iv = cryptokey.IV.fromLength(16);
    final encrypter = cryptokey.Encrypter(cryptokey.AES(key));

    final encryptedTitle = encrypter.encrypt(currentText, iv: iv);
    final encryptedDescription = encrypter.encrypt(descriptionText, iv: iv);


    databaseReference.child(v4Uuid).set({
      'yes': 0,
      'no': 0,
      'type': 'YesNo',
      'private' : 'no',
      'passphrase' : '',
      'creator' : auth.currentUser.uid,
      'titlecrypt':encryptedTitle.base64,
      'descriptioncrypt':encryptedDescription.base64
    });
```

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: Code in edit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.
It seems like the flutter plugin "firebase_app_check" causes the problem.
After removing it, it works fine again.